# Set umask for a sftp account?

Tags: unix, ssh, sftp

Could anyone tell me how to set the `umask`for a single `sftp` user? Worth mentioning is a **IBM AIX**...

Adding `umask 002` to that user's `.profile` didn't work... (the goal is that this user files are accesible to people from the same group).

I've seen somehowto's around editing the sftpd configs, though I want to set it for one user only, so I expected to find something that didn't need root access.

thanks!

f.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The user can set this up themselves without the involvement of root, either from the client (per connection) or on the server (per public key).

From the client, we can override the remote command used to handle the sftp interaction using the `-s` option:

```sh
sftp -s 'umask 0777; env PATH=${PATH}:/usr/libexec/openssh:/usr/lib/ssh:/usr/sbin sftp-server' username@hostname
```

(If your `sftp-server` is not installed in one of the locations mentioned above, add that to the path also).

From the server, we can force a particular command to be run whenever a connection is made using a particular public key.  This will get run for all connections, not just those for SFTP, but we can inspect the `$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND` environment variable to decide what course of action to take.  Adding something like the following to `authorized_keys` is probably sufficient for your needs:

```
command="umask 0777; if [[ -n $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND ]]; then eval $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND; else exec bash --login; fi" ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EA...
```

(substituting whichever is your favourite shell to handle any interactive logins, and noting that if you use `tcsh` you'll have to modify this to suit that shell's syntax).

Answer (score 26):

Worked great for me. However, needed a bit of research because what you provided is an extract from docs. A specific example in my case would be to put two consecutive lines at the end of /etc/ssh/sshd_config

```
Match Group www-data
ForceCommand internal-sftp -u 2
```

In my case what I wanted to do is to set umask to '002' (2 in decimal) if someone in group 'www-data' logs in.

There is also an option to use env. variable SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND instead of 'internal-sftp', but I did not have time to pursue that.

Comment: Careful when you do that. In the example above the whole group 'www-data' will not be able to do ssh through console. I get the error `This service allows sftp connections only.Connection to thrive closed.'.

Comment: This worked for me also (on Amazon Linux). I had previously been using the SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND method described above.  For some reason when I changed to sftp-internal and set up Chroot Directory the umask in authorized_keys stopped having any effect.  Thanks!

Comment: For most of us concerned with security of sftp users, chroot is THE solution. And this answer helped me to resolve issues of umask for these users without shell access or home directory. +1. However, this did not turn up quickly in search.

Comment: I've done this, and it works when I create files via command line sftp but not via FileZilla. Any ideas?

Comment: This worked for me but had to set it as `internal-sftp -u 002`

Comment: One thing to keep in mind ... umask only strips permissions it does not "add" or set them http://askubuntu.com/questions/44542/what-is-umask-and-how-does-it-work

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about AIX, but you should be able to do this with OpenSSH, though it will require root permissions. You'll need to write a wrapper script for the server component of sftp. The wrapper will need to selectively change the `umask` for the user and then `exec` the sftp server. For selecting a user, I'm partial to:

```
id --user
```

If you were to create such a script as `/usr/local/sbin/sftp-wrapper`, you would then change the configuration for the sftp subsystem in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` from:

```
Subsystem   sftp    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
```

to:

```
Subsystem   sftp    /usr/local/sbin/sftp-wrapper
```

Beyond writing the wrapper script, every step will require root permissions.

Comment: I believe the sftp server is started by root when you connect via sftp. Thus, the default umask derives from root's umask. I don't believe there is a way of altering this for a particular user from within that user's configuration. If you want to change the sftp umask for all users, you can make a simpler modification to the sftp subsystem configuration:

```
Subsystem   sftp    /bin/bash -c ‘umask 002; /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server’
```

Answer (score 1):

A umask of 111 in Octal will yield 73 in decimal, which we 
will use in this example.

```
#vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Add the following two lines at the end of the file to configure the sftp 
umask for a group of users.

```
Match Group  <group name>
ForceCommand  internal-sftp  -u 73
```

Or, add the following two lines at the end of the file to configure the sftp umask for a single user.

```
Match User   <user name>
ForceCommand  internal-sftp -u 73
```

Restart the sshd daemon.

```
#stopsrc -s sshd

#startsrc -s sshd
```

this will help : Aamod chandra

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why below lines do not work for me:

*Match Group

```
ForceCommand  internal-sftp  -u 73
```

At last add '-u 0002' for Subsystem works fine on SUSE 11.3:

```
*Subsystem sftp /usr/lib64/ssh/sftp-server **-u 0002***
```

and now specifiled user can only login with public key:

```
Match User nappcpr, Group iwcopy

    PasswordAuthentication no

    PubkeyAuthentication yes

    **KbdInteractiveAuthentication no**
```